# Is it good practice to View share all the settings table in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I created settings table like this.

id  key          value
1   title        title of the website
2   description  some text

And i did this in the base controller

```
public function __construct(){
    $settings = TSettings::all();
    View::share('settings', $settings);
}
```

Is it a good practice or not? and please if not why?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with using View share for all settings if you need them on all requests.

**However**, accessing them by index is bad. Don't rely on your database always being in the same default order.

Instead either use the [`->where(settingKey, settingName)`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-where)/some other collection method to access them or share them as separate variables for each setting.